# python3 print a value of an argument for a class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I created a pretty standard class for guests that will participate in an event (with their partners/children).

```
class Guest:
    def __init__(self, name, adult, child, infant):
        self.name = name
        self.adult = adult
        self.child = child
        self.infant = infant
```

and added several objects to it:

```
adam_s = Guest('Adam Smith', 2, 0, 1)
sandra_b = Guest('Sandra Bind', 2, 0,1)
alince_d = Guest('Alice Donovan',2,0,0)
parents_smith = Guest('Mr&Ms Smith', 2,0,0)
```

I'll be adding more and more objects to this class. At any point, I would like to be able to sum the number of all adults, children and infants for all objects using the Guest class.

I tried, the following but the result is not what I wanted (not giving me the actual values for each attribute).

```
for attr,value in vars(Guest).items():
    print(attr, value)
```

It's probably a very nooby question but I've been searching for a while and I couldn't find a solution to it.

Comment: You're not adding objects to the class though... you're creating new instances of the class with certain information. You can store those instances in a list such as `guests = [adam_s, sandra_b, alince_d]` etc... and then you can loop over those and performance calculations etc... eg: `sum(g.adult for g in guests)` to get the count of adult guests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
sum_adult=[]

    class Guest:
        def __init__(self, name, adult, child, infant):
            self.name = name
            self.adult = adult
            self.child = child
            self.infant = infant

            sum_adult.append(self.adult)


    adam_s = Guest('Adam Smith', 2, 0, 1)
    sandra_b = Guest('Sandra Bind', 2, 0,1)
    alince_d = Guest('Alice Donovan',2,0,0)
    parents_smith = Guest('Mr&Ms Smith', 2,0,0)

    print(sum(sum_adult))
```

output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
class Guest:
    adultCounter = 0
    def __init__(self, name, adult, child, infant):
       # your code here
       Guest.adultCounter +=1
```

and then you can call the value like this:

```
print ('Total adults: {}'.format(Guest.adultCounter))
```

Comment: Hi! The above gives the count of the each instance of the argument used so it may be useful in some cases. I wanted to sum up the values for all adults values so the previous response does the job. Anyway, thank you for your feedback as I'll surely make use of an incrementing counter in future scripts!